# Integral transforms involving logarithms?

Tags: soft-question, integral-transforms

We have the fourier-transform:

$$F\{f\}(w) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)\exp(iwx)dx$$

Which has extremely many applications and interpretations throughout science and engineering. For instance since it has the famous convolution rule: $$F(f*g) = F(f)\cdot F(g)$$
which can be used to speed up convolutions, it also has special differentiation and integration rules:
$$F\left\{\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\right\}(w) = wiF\{f\}(w)$$
$$F\left\{\int f\right\}(w) = \frac{F\{f\}(w)}{iw}$$
making it very useful in solving differential equations.

---

So I have thought about what happens if we replace the complex exponential with a logarithm:

$$L\{f\}(w) = \int_{0}^\infty f(x)\log(wx)dx$$

Do you think this would make sense to investigate? Could it have any interesting properties? Are there any other integral transforms involving logarithms which are interesting or useful?

---

**EDIT** Observation by Tom-Tom, we can rewrite it as:

$$\int_0^\infty f(x)\log(\omega x)\mathrm dx= \left(\int_0^\infty f(x)\mathrm dx\right)\log(\omega) +\int_0^\infty f(x)\log(x)\mathrm dx = a \log(w) + b$$
with constants: $a$ is the integral of $f$ and $b$ is a log-weighted integral of $f$.

Comment: One of the key in Fourier transforms is that derivatives are transformed into product by $\mathrm i\omega$ and convolutions into products of transforms.

Comment: Yes you are right, I can add that to the description in the question if you want.

Comment: Another remark : $$\int_0^\infty f(x)\log(\omega x)\mathrm dx=
\left(\int_0^\infty f(x)\mathrm dx\right)\log(\omega)
+\int_0^\infty f(x)\log(x)\mathrm dx.$$
Seeing this, your attempt for transform is just of function of the form $a\log(\omega)+b$.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Do you think it could get more interesting if we put a function of $w$ as upper limit of the integral?

Comment: I think you should first clearly chose the properties of the transformation that you want.